# Weird problem with json rendering of model of relationship in Rails 3.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, relationship

I've got a relationship through a one_to_many :though relationship:

```
  has_one :todays_order, :through => :patient_orders, :source => :daily_order ,:conditions => ["order_for_date = ?", Date.today]
```

But when I want to render that in a controller like that:

```
    respond_with(@daily_order = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]).todays_order)
```

I'll get the following response:

> {"marked_for_destruction"=>false,
>    "changed_attributes"=>{},
>    "attributes"=>
>     {"additional_information"=>"....", "id"=>"594369222"},
>    "readonly"=>false,
>    "errors"=>{},
>    "previously_changed"=>{},
>    "destroyed"=>false,
>    "attributes_cache"=>{},
>    "new_record"=>false}

But output should be something like that:

> {"additional_information"=>"....", "id"=>"594369222"}

Whats wrong here?

P.S.: You can find the complete Controller and Model: http://pastebin.com/VSbvesTn

Comment: Could you post the full code of the action (or even the controller)?

Comment: why dont you use `render :json => @daily_order`

Comment: also from your output, you can get the desired output with `respond_with(@daily_order["attributes"])`

Comment: You can find the complete controller and model at http://pastebin.com/VSbvesTn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by not rendering the patient.todays_order "relationship", instead i'm rendering result of an AR query.
So I think you cant render a relationship object directly in rails.